# virtocommerce Cash on Delivery payment

Tags: virtocommerce

In virtocommerce there is many online payment method. My customer also want to pay cash on delivery. Can I use or implement the cash on delivery payment method on virtocommerce ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently virtocommerce has a **Manual payment test method** it payment method not required for customer any payment process you can adapt it for you requirements.

How to develop you custom payment method you can read here
http://docs.virtocommerce.com/display/vc2devguide/Creating+new+payment+method